# How can I show offline data if network is slow or if firebase didn't respond quickly?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working recently on an android chat application based on Firebase realtime database and using Offline data persistance.

The problem I'm facing is that when I first open the app, it takes some time to get data from firebase database, so when i open a conversation, if the network is slow it takes sometime to show messages and sometimes it can go to few seconds or more of blank chat conversation!!

I had enabled offline persistance and when there is no network everything is showing up correctly and quickly, but when there is a network connexion it takes some time and it's what I don't want to because when we say Chat we say realtime without latency!

I was thinking about adding all my firebase database data into sqlite and show it from local db at the first time!

Is there any way to make my app shows always offline data and when firebase connexion works fine synchronize the data? if not, how about using sqlite? and how to keep my data synchronized?

Comment: You can use shared preferences for each chat. When you open for first time save the chat in shared preferences. And later when it is opened again show the cached chat data and syn with firebase in background.

Comment: It sounds like you have disk persistence enabled, in which case Firebase will already return data from the disk cache straight away. If that's not what you're seeing, update your question to show the minimal code with which you can reproduce the slow behavior, preferably just with logging output (since the problem is likely unrelated to your UI), and with timing results in there. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can't put code because the code is just working fine, the problem is in the  results and the latency of showing data.. about the persistence i just activated offline persistance by using : FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);